# How can I disable a root certificate in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security, certificate

I want to disable all root certificates in iOS since I'll be using a proxy to access all HTTPS sites.

How do I disable all root certs in iOS?

Comment: Are you jailbroken?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, but I can't confirm for sure. You could deactivate root certificates you added to your phone, but not the ones already in it...
I'll try to find some doc about it.